# How to get only the last executed query result in a stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, multiple-resultsets

I have created a stored procedure which has 5 or more SELECT queries in it. However, the last SELECT query is written to return a resultset when the stored procedure is called. When I called this stored procedure from VB.Net, it returns all the 5 SELECT query results. How can I make it to return only the 5th SELECT query result?